# WCFサービス上でシングルトンのクラスを利用するとインスタンスは共有されますか？

Tags: c#, iis, wcf

掲題の件、WCFサービスのクラスでシングルトンのクラスを利用しようとしています。
その場合、AサービスでシングルトンのクラスSを生成した後、
Bサービスで再びSのインスタンスを取得した場合、Aサービスで取得したSのインスタンスと
Bサービスで取得したSのインスタンスは同一のインスタンスとなりますか？

WCFサービスが動作するJavaでいうとTomcat上で動作しているイメージがあるので、
上記のような場合、どうなるのか知りたいです。
なお、ここで言っているシングルトンのクラスとはWCFサービスのシングルトンサービスの
ことではありません。例えば、InstanceContextMode.PerCallやPerSessionのサービス内で
シングルトンクラスを利用した場合の話になります。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

単純に`static`フィールドを利用してシングルトンパターンを実装している場合の動作ということでしょうか。これは各サービスのホスティング状況によります。

`static`フィールドのスコープは`AppDomain`ですので、`AppDomain`もしくはより上位のホスティングしているプロセス(IISであればワーカープロセス)が変化している場合は値が共有されません。IISの同じアプリケーション上にサービスを配置して1サーバーで動作させる場合であれば、プロセスがリサイクルされると値がリセットされることなります。これは標準設定だと20分ごとに発生します。

ですので数分間有効な簡単なキャッシュ程度であれば通常のシングルトンパターンを利用できますが、確実性を求めるのであればDBその他のバックエンドを利用した方が良いです。

Comment: 単純にstaticフィールドを利用してシングルトンパターンを実装している場合の動作となります。IISの同じアプリケーション上にサービスを配置して1サーバーで動作させる場合を想定していますので、シングルトンクラスの値が時間が経つとリセットされるという認識でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 基本的にシングルトンクラスの動作設定は、設定ファイルに記載しており、
インスタンス取得後、初期化処理をしてシングルトンクラスに保持しています。
その保持している値が、インスタンスごと時間が経つとリセットされてしまうと認識しております。
これは、問題ですので念のため、シングルトンクラスのインスタンス取得後、
初期化処理をしていなければ、毎回初期化処理をして設定ファイルの
内容を読み込んだほうが良いと理解しました。

Comment: シングルトンクラスのインスタンスだけがリセットされることはないです。IIS上ではプロセスが定期的に再起動されており、そのタイミングでプロセス上の全フィールドと同様にシングルトンインスタンスの状態も失われるということです。

Comment: なるほど、シングルトンクラスだけではなくて、シングルトンクラスを生成した
プロセスごとリセットされるということですね。
理解しました。ありがとうございます。